# Multiple minimum spanning tree graph

Tags: graph-theory

I am stuck over a condition. I want to know what are the cases where a graph can have multiple minimum spanning tree?
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What do you mean `what are there cases`? A simple example is a three node clique with value `1` on each edge. There are three different MSTs in this example

Answer (score 2):

A graph can have more than one MST in the case where both trees have the same overall weight but different paths to complete the tree.

Answer (score 1):

I answering with assumption that you have a graph with some edge weights and want to know if there is any other MST present.

You can do this by following method:

1. Find the edges in MST having same weight as some other edge *not* in MST.
   For example let's say edge ( a , b ) is in MST and has weight equal to edge ( c , d ).
2. Remove edge ( a , b ) from the graph and run MST again.
3. Repeat until you find no other such edge or MST with equal overall weight.

Remember for a graph to have different MSTs, atleast two edges must be equal .

Answer (score 0):

In a weighted, undirected graph G, a spanning tree T is a subgraph of G, if it is acyclic, connected, connecting all of the vertices in G with minimum total weight.
Multiple MST is only possible if there is

1. more than one spanning tree and
2. duplicate edge weights, which means graph G should have repeating equal weigth edges
3. and finally as a fine print, obviously, these multiple MSTs share the same minimum total weight.